# Public Key Error (Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication. Please contact your network administrator.)

Tags: networking, server, ssh

Recently we have install firewall certificate in all our users devices all is working fine except ubuntu/Linux laptops. browsing is working fine, but when users try fetch git repo or clone the same they are getting below error.

Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication. Please contact your network administrator.

Please let me know how i can resolve this issue.

Comment: is port 22 open through the firewall?

Comment: yes for outbound it is open

Comment: using git protocol

Comment: so what happens if you switch to https?

Comment: it works, but git is not working.

Comment: presumably port 22 is not open then.

Comment: all ports are open in outbound direction

Comment: You say that but the evidence is, that where your problem lies.